# How does radon calculate cycloMatic complexity of a class?

Tags: python, code-metrics, cyclomatic-complexity, flake8

I ran `radon cc -s myFile.py`  to calculate Cyclo metrics for it, I have pasted part of the result below

```
...
(more stuff)
C 37:0 MyClass - A (3)
M 40:4 MyClass.letter - A (2)
M 47:4 MyClass.fullname - A (2)
M 58:4 MyClass.__str__ - A (1)
...
(more stuff)
```

The [Documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/radon/latest/radon.pdf) for Radon doesn't specify how the metric will be calculated for class particularly. For me, it doesn't make sense for a class to have cyclomatic complexity as it doesn't represent a code flow by itself like a method or a function would do , and even if there was I would expect the Cyclomatic complexity for the class to be the sum of CCs for its methods, which is clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation: https://github.com/rubik/radon/blob/f11f905d3c1b9a300dcb811ddf714902e087beee/radon/visitors.py#L122-L283

It appears there is a setting which makes radon start counting at 0 instead of counting at 1, though it's unclear from their documentation how to trigger this

It doesn't appear that this is a standard form of complexity counting such as [McCabe's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) but one that's slightly more practical for python (choosing for instance to treat `try` blocks specially)